# Pixelmon model loading issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

I literally have no idea how to fix this. I've looked and looked and I've found no solution. I've reinstalled it many times. I've checked my files against someone else's that has no issues with their pixelmon mod and we have the same files, same sizes, everything.

Does anyone have any idea?

[image: And this is Cyndaquil]

[image: welp; This is what Charmander Looks like.]

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working.

I gave up on trying to fix it and looked into shaders, when I downloaded this [shader mod](http://adf.ly/WCpRN) and put it in the mod folder the models all worked! To confirm, I removed the shaders mod and went back on my world the models became glitchy again.

You will also need the [Minecraft Forge Installer](http://adf.ly/673885/http://files.minecraftforge.net/minecraftforge/minecraftforge-installer-1.6.4-9.11.1.916.jar.bcf) to get the shaders mod but Forge still runs Pixelmon.

Try this and see if it helps.

Comment: I love you. YOU have no idea how much LOL. Thank you so much <3 I was thinking about trying a shader; But wasn't sure which to look at so THAAAAAANKYOOOOOOOU <3 ^.^

Comment: @Pebbles - If this answer worked for you, you should mark it as accepted. Click the outlined checkmark under the vote count

Answer (score 0):

If you have other mods installed, this may not work. Also, your computer may have some problem with the mod itself.

Attempt to copy the entire Minecraft folder onto another's computer and see if it works then. Vice versa, try copying *their* files onto your computer and see if it works.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested; It works on every other computer in my house but when I swap the files from that computer onto this one It just goes back to the "Broken" Version. And is again problematic.

Comment: @Pebbles This problem is probably with your computer. Have you backed up your saves, completely deleted and reinstalled minecraft (and replacing your saves) and reinstalled pixelmon? That may work. You may have a stray '.CLASS' file or something like that somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the only thing is your graphics card can't handle the pixelmon textures. At least that is what happens to mine.